# user-scalable=no not working, is it still supported?

Tags: ios, iphone, zooming

I'm working on a website. I need to prevent the zoom-in animation when the user selects a form, however i'm trying with this code

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

and it doesn't work. I can't find anything, it seems like i'm the only one facing this issue. Is it still supported in newer iOS versions? Most posts i found are pretty old

Comment: I am in the same boat, just noticed it is no longer being recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Landed on this post having the same problem.
Turns out it seem to be required to have a css width specified on the html and/or body. At least it started working by adding this